# Why is asp.net core logging not filtering by categories that begin with?

Tags: logging, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core and it logs quite a few "info" level messages on application start that I want to filter out. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x#log-filtering) imply that a filtering rule specifying a category should match all categories starting with that category (i.e. `"Microsoft"` matches `"Microsoft*"`.)

My application has the default logging setup via `CreateDefaultWebBuilder` and so I placed the following in my `appsettings.json`:

```
"Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning",
        "Microsoft": "Warning"
    }
}
```

Contrary to my expectation, this did not work. However, the following did:

```
"Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure": "Warning"
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Surely I shouldn't need to list every category explicitly?

Comment: Just to check, are you running in `Development` and you also have a `appsettings.Development.json`?

Comment: Thank you. You hit the nail on the head. I do, and it has `"Microsoft": "Information"`. I was changing the wrong file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default ASP.NET Core templates already come with both an `appsettings.json` and a `appsettings.Development.json`. The latter file is an environment-specific one which will apply *on top of the default* if you are running in `Development` mode.

You are correct that a configuration key `"Microsoft"` will apply to all `Microsoft.*` namespaces. But only if there isn’t a more specific one, i.e. the most-specific configuration will win.

The default development settings file will set the `Microsoft` prefix to `Information` and the default to `Debug`. This will overwrite what you have specified in the `appsettings.json`, so the effective level for `Microsoft` will still be the default `Information`. Only when you use more specific namespaces, you can overwrite the setting from the development settings configuration.

In the end, you should make sure you are editing the right file. `appsettings.json` should contain those configurations that apply to *any* environment. These should basically be the production defaults. The `appsettings.Development.json` should then be used when you want a different configuration during development only. So it’s likely that you want to edit this here.